# Which preposition should be used in this translation? "Analysis… through/with/by neural networks"

Tags: prepositions, translation, german, by-with

I am not a native English speaker, so I have a quick question.
I have to translate my thesis' title into English.

This is the German sentence:

> Analyse und Anomalieerkennung elektrischer Verbraucher durch Neuronale
> Netzwerke

My wordly English translation would be as follows:

> Analysis and anomaly detection of <s>electrical consumers</s> electical devices *through* neural
> networks

I am not quite sure about the word "through" in this context. I would rather use the word "with" or maybe "by" (but I do not quite like this).

> Analysis and anomaly detection of <s>electrical consumers</s> electical devices  *with* neural
> networks.

EDIT:
By "electrical consumers" I was referring to a device using electrical energy, to avoid further confusion I would use "electrical devices" instead.

Comment: Maybe “using Neural Networks”?

Comment: Yes, I like it.

Comment: A verb would help the sentence.

Comment: @YosefBaskin The German original isn't a sentence, so I don't think the English translation needs to be one. Just delete the period at the end.

Comment: The term "electrical consumers" is confusing.  Does it mean people who consume electricity (given that "consumer" is most commonly used to refer to a person or business), or are you referring to devices that use electricity?

Comment: You could tell us more about your study for us to help with word choices.

Comment: My research tells me that electrical consumers are also used for electrical devices and are also used mainly for those.

Comment: I think the only time I've seen "electrical consumers" in this sense has been in a translation from Russian...

Comment: Probably "electrical devices" is good; possibly "electrical appliances", with a slightly different meaning

Comment: I think the preposition before "electrical consumers" is more problematic. "Analysis of" is fine, but "detection in" or "detection for" would be better.

Comment: If even, it's a misunderstanding between colloquial and technical language. If asking me,  persons who use an electrical device are not a consumer because they are not really consume the energy but use it. I think it would be quite wrong to call people using electrical devices consumers.

Comment: Context matters. In common parlance, a "consumer" is an end user of a product or service. So in casual conversation, if you said "electrical consumers" I might think you meant customers who pay for electrical service. In a technical context it might be different, but still ambiguous enough.

Comment: What about *electrical appliance purchasers*? Is that what is meant?

Comment: I think I would go with electical devices.

Comment: I'd say my washing machine is an "elektrischer Verbraucher", not me as the owner and user of that washing machine.

Comment: I think "electricity consumers" is the best way to put it. (Also "by neural netwroks".)

Comment: If the reference is to the devices themselves, as things that use electricity, then *electrical appliances* is a common term.

Comment: In German, we would not refer to people using electrical devices as electrical consumers.
That's why, and because of the website suggested so, I used the term "electrical consumes". I think I would go with "electrical devices".

Comment: @YosefBaskin : The original appears to be a **title**, rather than a sentence — just as the name of Freud’s book *Civilisation and Its Discontents* (translating from *Das Unbehagen in der Kultur*, “The Uneasiness in Civilisation”) is not a sentence.

Answer (score 8):

*Durch* also has the English senses *through*, *via* and **with**.

The word *by* could also be used in the example in English, and *by means of* would fit too.

[Wiktionary *by means of*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/by_means_of)
Preposition
by means of
by using (an object or an approach).

(See
[wordreference.com *durch*](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/durch)
durch Präp  (mithilfe, mittels) (via)
through prep
via prep
with prep

Comment: Yes, "by means of" is less ambiguous than"through" or "with'.

Comment: "Durch also has the English senses through, via and with."
I know that, but there is often a slightly different semantics behind the words. And there is also the stile to be considered. What is a good stile? I liked the idea posted in a comment to use the word "using". But I am not a native speaker, so I can't really be sure if this is legit and whether it's a good stile.

Comment: Agree that "through" could be confusing, as it can carry a physical connotation. They electrical consumers through neural networks could be misunderstood by a non-expert to mean - electrical consumer moving through or scattered through a neural network.

 "By means of" is less ambiguous but a bit wordy. "With" or "via" seem like the optimal choice if you are looking to balance legibility with brevity.

Comment: @BenjaminPopper The audience for a thesis is readers familiar with the subject area, so you don't really need to worry about misunderstandings by lay people. You should emulate terminology common in the field.

Answer (score 8):

In the context of a thesis title, I don't think "through" is out of place here at all, in fact I'd expect it. I've seen many thesis titles that use the word "through" in exactly the same sense.

It is a little formal sounding - if you said it in casual conversation it might raise eyebrows - but nobody would think that you're talking about the electrical consumers literally *physically going through* a neural network.

However, I would second (or third) the notion that using "electrical consumers" here is too ambiguous for English speakers. If you mean devices that consume electricity, use "electrical devices" or "electrical appliances". If you mean power grid consumers (i.e. people) use "electrical service consumers".

Answer (score 4):

> Analyse und Anomalieerkennung elektrischer Verbraucher durch Neuronale Netzwerke

The use of neural networks in the analysis of, and anomaly detection in, the consumption of electricity.

Comment: I concur. Sometimes for clear translations the word order is changed, viz. my above comment using the example of Freud’s *Das Unbehagen in der Kultur* — translated as *Civilisation and Its Discontents*.